# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key XXXXXX

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

when i try to build and run my app, it crashes and i got this in the log :

```
reason: '[<LoadingViewController 0x6b2c5a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key aproposViewController.'
```

the strange is that `aproposViewController` is not used in `LoadingViewController`, it's just another view controller in my app. please help, thx in advance :)

**EDIT**

**appdelegate.h :**

```
@class LoadingViewController;

@interface TopStationAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    LoadingViewController *loadingView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet LoadingViewController *loadingView;
@end
```

**appdelegate.m** :

```
#import "LoadingViewController.h"
@implementation TopStationAppDelegate
@synthesize window;
@synthesize loadingView;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
  [window addSubview:loadingView.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [loadingView release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

there is no declaration of aproposViwController, even in IB for the main view !!
**EDIT 2**
here two screenshot of my besic set in the main and loadingView in interface builder :
[image]

[image]

Comment: you can open the aproposViewController.xib file and check if there are any warnings at the bottom right corner of the window. If not than check the inspector, (info tab.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Can't be sure if this is what's happening in your case, but you'll commonly see this message if you have a connection set up in your nibs to assign an object to a property of another object, but the property is missing on the target object.

So you might have had an IBOutlet named aproposViewController on LoadingViewController at one point, connected another view controller to it in the nib, and then removed the IBOutlet but neglected to remove the connection in the nib.

So when the nib is loaded, it tries to set the property, only to find it doesn't exist, hence:

```
reason: '[<LoadingViewController 0x6b2c5a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key aproposViewController.'
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer, actually `LoadingViewController` is the first view to show after my app finish launching, i have edited my question, please have a look :)

Comment: Check all of the connections and object types in your MainWindow.xib and LoadingViewController.xib. I think you'll find one that shouldn't be there. Unfortunately it's very hard to troubleshoot nibs from afar, but if there is no code trying to set aproposViewController then it's a safe bet the nib is the problem.

Comment: Hi again, i have edited my question, this two screen shots show the connections in IB, i'm gonna be crazy, i use to do this stuff easily, i don't know why it doesnt' be implemented this time !!!

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and it was because I had an:

```
vc = [[someVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"oldNibFileNameButCachedSomewhereWithOldRefToPropertyIn" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 4):

If you removed the connection to IBOutlet from XIB and still it happens

Then delete the app from simulator and run again.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the same error in my Application and I found solution for this after some time.

Actually I Have given 2 action events for one button.
I have removed extra connection which is assigned to button after that the problem is over.

This is worked in my scenario. I hope it will be helpful to someone else..