# [<UIView 0x89bfd40> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

Another problem that is causing my build to succeed, then terminate. As follows:

Error:

```
2013-09-30 20:21:23.708 The Solver[2566:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIView 0x89bfd40> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key welcomeBeta.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x023615e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014bf8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x023f16a1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x00f73c2e -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x00edff3b _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 88
    5   Foundation                          0x00edf493 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
    6   UIKit                               0x0008f97b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) setValue:forKey:] + 168
    7   Foundation                          0x00f4194a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
    8   UIKit                               0x002c6cd5 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
    9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014d17d2 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0235cb6a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
    11  UIKit                               0x002c582e -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1417
    12  UIKit                               0x00137c95 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
    13  UIKit                               0x0013843d -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
    14  UIKit                               0x0013873e -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    15  UIKit                               0x00138c44 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    16  UIKit                               0x000615ad -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
    17  UIKit                               0x00061947 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
    18  UIKit                               0x00061bdd -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    19  UIKit                               0x0006c44a -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
    20  UIKit                               0x0001f8e0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1851
    21  UIKit                               0x00023fb8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    22  UIKit                               0x0003842c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
    23  UIKit                               0x00038999 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    24  UIKit                               0x00025c35 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x022bf2eb _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x022bedf6 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x022dcdd5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x022dcb0b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x023077ec __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x02306b33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x0230694b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    32  UIKit                               0x000236ed -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    33  UIKit                               0x0002594b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    34  The Solver                          0x000033dd main + 141
    35  libdyld.dylib                       0x059a5725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Code for UIControllerView with welcomeBeta (Button)

WelcomeUI.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WelcomeUI : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *welcomeStart;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *welcomeBeta;

@end
```

WelcomeUI.m:

```
#import "WelcomeUI.h"

@interface WelcomeUI ()

@end

@implementation WelcomeUI

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Please let me know where I'm going wrong. Also explain in detail as I'm new to objective-c and Xcode.

Comment: what's question here?  It just looks like you want someone to debug your code for you.

Comment: I've tried playing with the button on both ends, I've tried resetting it, rewriting the code. I'm new at this, and I've no clue what I'm doing wrong, I'm trying to find a fix, and learn from my mistake.

Comment: Try the answers in the link below

[stackoverflow.com/questions/5930492/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-xxxxxx][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930492/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-xxxxxx

Comment: THANK YOU! I'm using a view controller, and had to redo my code and the link between views.