# iOS - AppDelegate this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, appdelegate

After trying to implement [A replica of Path’s table view](http://kentnguyen.com/ios/knpathtableviewcontroller/), I'm getting this weird error.

```
'[<InboxViewController 0xcb1b260> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.'
```

As suggested by these threads, [remove-IBOutlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930492/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-xxxxxx), I tried removing the `IBOutlet` connection. Still not working.

The problem arises when I include

```
@interface InboxViewController : KNPathTableViewController <NetworkEngineDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate> .
```

The apps work fine when `UIViewController` is used instead of `KNPathTableViewController` like this :

```
 @interface InboxViewController : KNPathTableViewController <NetworkEngineDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Below is my storyboard screenshot.

[image: IBOutlet]

When I removed the `Table View` connection, the error disappeared. I got a blank screen (as there is no connection in the Outlet).

What could be the problem??

Answer (score 0):

`KNPathTableViewController` declares the `tableView` property as `readonly` so no setter method is generated. Usually that wouldn't be an issue, but internally the instance variable is defined as:

```
@synthesize tableView = __tableView;
```

Which breaks the automatic KVC support.

The intended usage is that you call `initWithStyle:infoPanelSize:` which creates and sets the private reference to the table view...

Comment: Thanks @Wain. I'm using storyboard and hence I have to use `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder`. Can you give me an example of how to implement it?

Comment: You will need to change the `KNPathTableViewController` class to make the `tableView` property writable and to do any other config in `initWithCoder:`. Mostly a renaming job.