# Navigate to loginViewController when Session facebook login is closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, iboutlet

I'm a newbie of xcode and i have a question.
I want to create a facebook login application, but i have a problem when i want to navigate from mainView to loginViewControl. I have found, tried, and tried but I have no solutions.

http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/2e63/7p37k32d13xs2zkfg.jpg

When the app starts, FB will check for session, if a session is cached, the MainTabBarController will load without problems.
But I can't navigate the app to the LoginUIViewController when no session is cached.
I put my (void)pushToLoginView function in to .m file of MainTabBarController but I tried many ways and it not works
Here is the code of the MainTabBarController.m

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];


    if (FBSession.activeSession.state != FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        [self pushToLoginView];
    }
}

- (void)pushToLoginView {
    LoginUIViewController *loginView = [[LoginUIViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:loginView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The error is:

```
2014-03-21 21:44:53.367 FB Media[5815:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<LoginUIViewController 0xa56ee70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nameLabel.'
```

UPDATE 1: I edited my function pustToLoginView like this:

```
- (void)pushToLoginView {
    LoginUIViewController *loginView;
    self.view = loginView.view;
}
```

And it's worked, but the loginView's brank new and have nothing (loginButton didn't appear).
So I think i have a problem when connected from code to UserInteface.
So please have me!

Comment: Outlet issue in interface builder. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key), [and here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930492/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-xxxxxx), as well as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793162/setvalueforundefinedkey-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-k)

Comment: Do you have a UILabel in your LoginUIViewController that you had connected to a IBOutlet and recently deleted / changed it?

Comment: @Tander, I have none, It's simply the logo of the app, i deleted is because of personal reason. Just a loginButton, I have image in the post

Comment: According to the error: nameLabel is the issue. Where is that located?

Comment: interface LoginUIViewController : UIViewController

property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *loginButton;

end

Comment: I have no Object named nameLabel. I think this error when creating loginUIViewController

Comment: The error code differs from your last comment. The code you posted doesn't have the issue. Its definitely an error in InterFace Builder with one of your objects.(nameLabel) - do a search in your project with the term nameLabel and see what comes up.

Comment: I changed to 
LoginUIViewController *loginView = [[LoginUIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"loginView" bundle:nil];

Comment: And now, the error is *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:  with name 'loginView''

Comment: That error is because you're trying to load a nib file that doesn't exist. Do you have a nib (.xib) that is called loginView in your project? if not - then that is why you're getting the error. As I said earlier - the original code you posted does not have an issue with it.

Comment: why you are trying to load a nib, when you have a storyboard ? your pushToLoginView implementation is totally wrong. you should load LoginUIViewController from storyboard.

Comment: @pawan, how can i load exiting ViewController from LoginUIViewController? It's exactly what i need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should load LoginUIViewController from storyboard

```
LoginUIViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginUIViewController"];
```

check this [Instantiate a view controller using a storyboard identifier](http://sketchytech.blogspot.in/2012/11/instantiate-view-controller-using.html)

[create a View Controller defined in you your Storyboard programmatically](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-create-a-view-controller-defined-in-you-your-storyboard-programmatically/)