# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key screenNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, crash, uncaught-exception

I have 2 computers running the same iOS code in Xcode (in a dropbox folder).
When creating an UIViewController, it works properly on one machine when the other gives: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key screenNumber.

I have absolutely no reference of screenNumber in the code, and do not use any storyboard neither xib for this specific class.

Command that inits the view:

```
ChildViewController *childViewController = [[ChildViewController alloc] initWithIndex:index :100];
```

It crashes at random locations in this code:

```
 -(ChildViewController *)initWithIndex:(int)index :(int)maximumIndex
    {
        self = [super init];

        if (self)
        {
            NSLog(@"Init child:%d",index);
            // Custom initialization

            self.index=index;
            maxIndex=maximumIndex;
         }

        return self;
    }
```

ChildViewController is derived from UIViewController.
Error message received is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ChildViewController 0x8e0f4d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key screenNumber.'
```

Any idea if I could potentially find the screenNumber reference in another folder that would not be in the project directory ? I don't exclude I may have used this variable in the past but not anymore.

Thanks

Comment: And what does the exception stack look like when it fails?  And what is the *exact* exception message.

Comment: To answer the above questions, go to the *Breakpoint Navigator* and enable the *exception breakpoint* (click the plus `+` sign in the lower left corner).

Comment: Hi, what is childviewcontroller being derived from? is there an iboutlet that has to be bound? maybe you find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930492/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-xxxxxx

Comment: you can use extern keyword to exclude information form one project to another.

Comment: Changed text in question. Error message is described now and ChildViewController is derived from UIViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the issue. The simulator still had old files in it. Deleted home/Preferences/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/.